Use IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Framework 4.8
I know this question has been asked several times, but after a long search through all the answers, I couldn't find an answer that explains how to use the IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Framework (4.8), with sample code.
Because of problems listed here, It is recommended to use one instance of HttpClient and manage the instances by using IHttpClientFactory.
I followed all the steps as I understood, but I did not find a clear explanation.
My code needs to make API calls to charge credit cards of customers who shop on the site.
The questions:

Am I working correctly with the code attached below?
is it safe to charge in this way several customers who buy at the same time (or there will be conflicts in calls)?

I would appreciate any sample code that would explain or confirm the code below,
I mention that this is ASP.NET Framework and not Core!
I installed Microsoft.Extensions.Http
I created a static field with instance of IHttpClientFactory in a non-static class.
I used using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
public class MyService
{
    private static IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public static IHttpClientFactory GetClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (_clientFactory == null)
            {
                var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

                serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("someAPI");
                var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
                _clientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            }
            return _clientFactory;
        }
    }
}


In the billing process I used this code:
with using System.Net.Http; and using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using (var client = MyService.GetClient.CreateClient("someAPI"))
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://api.xxx.com/xxx", new StringContent(stringData, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ChargeAPIResponse chargeAPIResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ChargeAPIResponse>().Result;
        // success - do something
    }
    else
    {
        // failed - do something
    {
    client.Dispose();
}


Is there a more correct way of working?
I would also appreciate a code sample.
Thank you!

Am I working correctly with the code attached below - no. There is no protection from creating serviceCollection many times. You are still Disposing the returned HttpClient, two times too. The DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add part belongs to the factory. And you are calling .Result everywhere.

@GSerg Thanks for the comment. If I understand you, I should avoid using the using block and also not use Dispose(), and also use the async and await method, and call Result later. But I didn't find a way without using serviceCollection. Do you maybe have an example of improved code?
